# Odd socket() error -- returns -1, but errno=ERROR_SUCCESS

Tags: c++, c, sockets, errno

I'm developing a dedicated game server on a linux machine, in C/C++ (mixed). I have the following snippet of code:

```
int sockfd=socket(AI_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(sockfd==-1)
{
    int err=errno;
    fprintf(stderr,"%s",strerror(err));
    exit(1);
}
```

My problem here, is that socket is returning -1 (implying a failure) and the error string is being printed, but it is "Success" (ERROR_SUCCESS).

Other notes:

- I am requesting a socket on a port >1024 (out of context, but thought I'd mention)
- I'm executing the app as the super user

Comment: Did you cut/paste the code from you app or re-type? If this is a re-type I would check that your code has == (compare) in the if and not an =(assignment).

Comment: It's a `==' all right...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I feel incredibly stupid. Carefully looking over my code, on my dev-computer shows:

```
if(sockfd==-1);
...
```

Comment: you are not the first one to do this, nor will you be the last one :-)

Comment: This is exactly why ERROR_SUCCESS exists. :-)

Comment: aviraldg, you might want to accept your own answer so the question appears as solved.

Comment: Let this be a lesson: Always copy and paste *real* code that demonstrates the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Do you have multiple threads running?  They could be overwriting the errno value.</strike>

Are there any lines of code between socket() and if() that you left out?  Another function call could overwrite the errno.

Comment: The C standard has no concept of threads. Though posix requires it to be thread local.